# What technology/technique is used in this track?

Tags: sound-design, audio-recording, sound-effects

Whenever I listen to this track, it feels like there is an additional sound applied to the singer's voice. The singer can sing very well, that's I know for sure, because I saw him live. By the way, in this track, there is an additional sound/feel used along with his singing; and that additional feel/sound makes the singing/voice more attractive and sharp.  What is this technology/technique known as?  Is this technology/technique applied by using only software or hardware or using both?

[I am talking about this track](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LQNpdlq4F0)

Listen from **0:18 to 0:57** ; **1:40 to 1:55** **very attentively**. I am **Not** talking about harmonization/echo here. I am talking about an extra layer of digital/computerized/artificial sound or something else which has been added in some/all parts of the track.

Comment: it's just auto tune, is that what you're after ?

Comment: oh ok. The singer is singing in correct pitch originally, and adding `autotune` makes the voice more attractive. Am I right? Can a free audio editing software give me that effect with my singing?

Comment: autotune is a very obtrusive effect. You may like it but others don't so when you say "Makes the voice more attractive" is not exactly true. It does what an effect does to a sound. I'm sure there are plenty free autotune effects out there , but im not Google. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you write your first comment as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is autotune effect.

Autotune started as a correction effect but quickly became a sensation. So it's currently used in most of the music we listen to.